# Import text (csv) file into Excel Table using VBA Macros

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am trying to import a text file automatically into Excel. It seems to import perfectly with the code as follows, however if I want it to import it into a table, it does not do so and results in the table moving to the right.

```
path = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.path)    

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path & "\Users 
Roles Entitlements.csv", Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
    .Name = "positions_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 857
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Lets assume the Table Name is Table1.

Would appreciate if someone could suggest an amendment to this code so it imports directly to Table1 and readjusts the Excel Table accordingly.

Comment: [`QueryTables.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add) creates a new query table. Are you perhaps looking for [`QueryTable.Refresh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.refresh)?

Comment: How did you set up the table the first time?  If you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform` in 2016+) to set up the table for the first time, and then use `Refresh` to update it.  Record a macro while doing these options if you must have it in VBA.